# Is It possible to Transpose Unlimited rows into column using PIVOT in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

Is It possible to Transpose Unlimited rows into column through PIVOT in SQL Server? if YES then How? I need because i have huge number of cities in table so i can't add all cities in `FOR City IN` of PIVOT.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding you problem, i mean in which situation you require all city names to transpose? I am sure you would get better solution for it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is It possible to convert Unlimited rows into column through PIVOT in
>   SQL Server?

No. You can have max 4,096 columns in a select statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx